# Include javadocs of dependencies inside dependencies

Tags: java, maven, dependencies, maven-plugin, jitpack

I am working on two things: The main project and its library.

I update the library regularly and use it in the main project.

My library gets released on Github and I get the release through https://jitpack.io.

Now I simply want to read the javadocs of my libraries dependecies, when I am using
the library in my main project.

This is how the `<build>` of my library looks like:

```xml
    <build>
        <finalName>${project.name}</finalName>
        <defaultGoal>clean package</defaultGoal>
        <plugins>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${java.version}</source>
                    <target>${java.version}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <createDependencyReducedPom>false</createDependencyReducedPom>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>attach-sources</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>jar</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>attach-javadocs</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>jar</goal>
                        </goals>
                       <configuration>
                            <includeDependencySources>true</includeDependencySources>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>

        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
            </resource>
        </resources>
    </build>
```

As you can see from the code above, I tried adding:

```xml
                       <configuration>
                            <includeDependencySources>true</includeDependencySources>
                        </configuration>
```

so the library can include the javadocs of its dependencies. But that didn't work. I get the following error:

```
Could not find artifact com.github.Osiris-Team:Dream-Yaml:pom:4.1 in central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2)
The POM for com.github.Osiris-Team:Dream-Yaml:jar:sources:4.1 is missing, no dependency information available
```

The error makes sense, because the `Dream-Yaml` dependency (of the library) is also released via Github (jitpack.io).

Is there any fix for this, besides releasing all my stuff on maven?